# ERROR: Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, geography-data-type

I'm trying to find out all the circles stored in the database(The circles are present all over the world) that intersect or overlap a given circle. I've stored the circles like this:

```
CREATE TABLE circles(gid serial PRIMARY KEY, name varchar, code integer, the_geog geography(POLYGON,4326) );

INSERT INTO circles (gid, name, code, the_geog) VALUES (1,"hello", 11,geometry(ST_Buffer(geography(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(48.732084 -3.459144)')), 1000)));
```

Now when I'm trying to find out all the circles that intersect a given circle, I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography.
```

I'm using this query to get the data:

```
select * from circles where st_intersects (circles.the_geog,ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-105.04428 39.74779)', 4326), 2877), 1500));
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that your [st_intersects](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html) mixes a geography and a geometry; I guess that Postgres is trying to cast your geometry to geography, and that fails because srid 2877 is, as your error messages says, not a lat/lon coordinate system.

Easiest way is to do everything using geographies and [st_geogfromtext](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_GeogFromText.html) (the [st_buffer](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Buffer.html) will also draw the circle in metres - if you use geometry it will use the coordinate system units).

```
select * from circles where 
st_intersects (
   circles.the_geog,
   ST_Buffer(       
              ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-105.04428 39.74779)')
              , 1500
   )
);
```

P.S. You can improve your insert query by not using the transform:

```
INSERT INTO circles (gid, name, code, the_geog) 
VALUES (
        1
        ,'hello' -- need single quotes here
        , 11
        ,ST_Buffer(ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(48.732084 -3.459144)'), 1000)
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ST_GeogFromText` instead of `ST_GeomFromText`

```
select * from circles where st_intersects (towers.the_geog,ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-105.04428 39.74779)', 4326), 2877), 1500));
```

Comment: Getting this error: ERROR:  function st_geogfromtext(unknown, integer) does not exist

Comment: Even if you fix the format of the ewkt (should be 'POINT(-105.04428 39.74779)' without the srid 4326), the st_transform fails because that only works on geometries.